# Advice defined has not been applied with AspectJ

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I have a AspectJ - Project with a aspect to making some `System.out.println`'s to learning a little bit about aspects etc.

The Problem is, that the advices which i define to the cuts doesn't work.
The warning which is shown is: `advice defined in ShapeAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]`

I'm working with a Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) and AspectJ Runtime: org.aspectj.runtime_1.8.5.20150128171000.jar, for the LTW  classes etc.: org.aspectj.weaver_1.8.5.20150128171000.jar and additionally org.aspectj.ajde_1.8.5.20150128171000.jar.

My simple defined aspect:

```
public aspect ShapeAspect {
   // pointcuts
   pointcut myPointcut2() : execution(oldshape.Point.new(..));

  // advices
  before() : myPointcut2(){
    System.out.println("Before init.");
  }
}
```

EDIT: Including Point class

```
 public class Point implements Shape{
    private int x,y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
      this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void draw(GC gc) {
      Color c = new Color(gc.getDevice(), 0, 0, 255);
      gc.setForeground(c);
      gc.drawPoint(this.x, this.y);
      c.dispose();
    }
 }

public class SWTMain{

   public static void main(String[] args){
     Shape s1 = new Point(4,4);
     s1.draw(gc);
   }
}
```

But at the line of `before()..` is the Warning: `advice defined in ShapeAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]`

What is the Problem here? On my PC with Windows it works correctly?

Comment: Are you asking if it's working on your pc with windows? Or is it just working?

Comment: On my pc with windows it is working corrently, that is confusing..

Comment: @Oni1, Did you ever figure out what was going on?  We are having issues with aspectj only on Mac right now.